# Why is Mongodb prefered over MySql for NodeJs development?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

> Please read before you answer:  I don't need any opinion-based answers or "nosql vs sql which is better" debates on the subject, just facts.

I want to slowly convert a php+mysql website I wrote with Symfony2 into a real time application using backbone with nodeJs + websockets.
I want to make a slow transition by changing single features, since I don't want to break a fully functional site.
I have been educating myself about NodeJs by reading books and watching Tutorials and there is one thing I noticed, I own more than 5 nodeJs books and none of them use MySql although its fully supported by node.
They all use MongoDB.

Here is my situation
 1. My Website is already integrated into MySql(Doctrine)
 2. My MySQL setup is fully functional and needs no improvements so far

I'm really frustated and I have a few questions:

1. Why is MySql not prefered although its a more mature piece of technology?
2. What are the advantages of moving to MongoDB over MySQL for the purpose of having a real-time application??

Comment: For me mongoDB is about JSON. Being able to work with JSONs is happiness.

Comment: nodejs works perfect with mysql...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen people choose Node/Mongo development because of the simplicity of the **all-JavaScript** stack, I've seen people choose Mongo because it's the **New Hotness**, and I've seen people choose Mongo because it's **actually the right tool for the job**: they have a large amount of document-like, unstructured data and/or they want to take advantage of Mongo's support for horizontal scaling, among other differences between MySQL and Mongo.

I'm not sure it's possible to answer this question in a non-opinion-based manner and without touching on Sql vs NoSql.  Mongo is simply a tool, and it happens to be free and commonly used in the field with Node.  If I were writing a Node tutorial, I'd probably choose Mongo too, because it's common and it's cool.

If Mongo is the right tool for your site's use cases, then the transition is probably worth it.  If MySQL is the right tool for your site, then congratulations! You've just saved a bunch of time rewriting your DB in Mongo.

As an aside- if your question uses the word "preferred", I can't really think of a way for it to *not* be opinion-based, by definition.